# JS scroll starts bottom. I want it start at top

Tags: javascript, jquery

The site I am working on:
http://bit.ly/OZSjT9

Please view source code.  I have so many different JS codes I think it's conflicting.

I am sooo new at Javascript that I have to get code online to get things to work.  Well my trouble is this.  Every time you load the page it starts at the bottom of the one page website.  It obviously should start at the top so that visitors will see the header first.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?  And how do I fix it?  Thanks so much!

```
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
            if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
            && location.hostname == this.hostname
            && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
              var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
               if ($target) {
                 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                 $(this).click(function() {
                   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 2000);
                   return false;
                 });
              }
            }
          });
```

Comment: Wow, I just learned something new.  Feel kinda silly now. :)

Comment: Good stuff! Unfortunately I cannot help with your problem though, but hopefully somebody else will soon!

Comment: Seems like the site in question does not respond at the moment, @user1461577. Can you try to reproduce the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I think it's because it's all on one page with a ton of JS stuff.  That's what client wanted so nothing I can do with all that content on one page.

Comment: Just added the section of code.

Answer (score 0):

by jquery  `.scrollTop()` this can be done for more reference [check this link](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to use pure javascript just use

```
scroll(0)
```

Comment: So in the case up top where could I place this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what are you asking about :)